Flutter: Navigator.pushNamed not recognizing path inside async function
I am trying to make a sign up page and take the user to home page when he signs up. This is my function I am calling.
Future<void> signUp(GlobalKey<FormState> registrationKey) async {
    if (registrationKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Account Created'),
            duration: Duration(
              milliseconds: 1500,
            ),
          )
      );
      print('start');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home_page');
      print('end');
    }
}

I have correctly set up /home_page and it works on other parts of the app
    routes: {
        '/welcome_page': (context) => const WelcomePage(),
        '/login_page': (context) => const LoginPage(),
        '/registration_page': (context) => const SignUpPage(),
        '/home_page': (context) => const HomePage(),
        '/add_product_page': (context) => const AddProductPage(),
        '/cart_page': (context) => const CartPage(),
      },

start is being printed on the terminal, but end is not printed
I/flutter (18150): start
E/flutter (18150): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/home_page", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

I tried moving Navigator.pushNamed outise the if condition but that too didn't seem to help.
I also tried replacing 'home_page' by 'add_product_page' but it had the same problem.

Solved it. I had used multiple MaterialApp widgets in my widget tree and the routes were inside the parent MaterialApp but Navigator was looking for routes inside the child MaterialApp. Removed the child MaterialApp and everything works.
